# JMeter does not load and gives error

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

My JMeter 3.0 installation was working fine and then I installed Selenium webdriver.
I copied the files and folders as mentioned in the installation steps given [here](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/leverage-your-load-testing-using-jmeter-and-selenium-webdriver/).
I get the following error:

Writing log file to: C:\WINDOWS\system32\jmeter.log

An error occurred: Implementing class

errorlevel=1

Press any key to continue . . .

If I remove the selenium installation it works as expected.

Can someone help me with what might have gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your jmeter.log file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guide you're using is quite outdated, currently recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/), so:

1. Install "clean" version of JMeter 3.0
2. Install [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
3. From JMeter main menu choose

   ```
   Options -> Plugins Manager -> Available Plugins -> Selenium/WebDriver Support
   ```

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager]
4. Click `Apply Changes and Restart JMeter

Plugins Manager is smart enough to detect and resolve libraries conflicts, moreover it is the handy way of managing the plugins and keeping them up-to-date.